# How to extend django.contrib.auth views?

Tags: django

**How I've Arranged Templates** : I have placed my `login.html` in `/templates/registration` folder of Django. So, the Django takes necessary care of `accounts/login` ,`accounts/logout` url requests and renders as per request. And I haven't to code for the individual `login` and `logout` functions.

**What I am trying to Achieve** : I want to authenticate users at login request, when they requests the login page:

- If user is anonymous user, I want to render the normal login page.
- However, If the user is authenticated thats already logged in. I want to display an error and not the logged page.

I want to achieve this in the *views.py* and *urls.py* and not in the templates by:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
```

### Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
                    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
                    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page' : 'Homepage'}, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to show an error if an already authenticated user is trying to login by visiting the login page?

Comment: @MiniGunnR: yeah right. But the problem was I had no idea how to achieve at the view level.

Comment: May I interest you in redirecting the user to the default landing page for logged in users instead of showing an error? This is exactly what happens as a standard. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the view with your own, which either redirects or calls the original.

```
def wrapped_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('whatever')
    else:
        return auth_views.login(request)
```

Comment: It pops 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'.

Comment: should be `request.user.is_authenticated`

Answer (score 1):

Provide `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in `settings.py`. Then use the following url for login page:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/',
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True),
        name='login'),
]
```

This will redirect your user to the URL provided in settings file if they try to login even after being authenticated.